# Why didn't Salazar shoot Jack Sparrow's ship when Jack performed the bootleg turn in front of the gate of the Devil's Triangle

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-men-tell-no-tales

If Salazar's mission in *Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Men Tell No Tales* was only to eradicate the pirates, then why didn't he do anything when his ship's left side faced Jack's ship? That's so much cannons in that side.

I mean he got plenty cannons and plenty of advisors, his ship was more like a floating Spanish fortress, and the crew had high morale.

Answer (score 5):

> ...when his ship's stern faced Jack's ship?

Well actually, the stern never faced Jack's ship but...

> I mean he got plenty cannons...

Not at the rear he doesn't...it looks like he's only got 4 (maybe 6) and half of those probably couldn't be brought to bear on Jack's ship as they are facing the wrong side.

[image]

> then why didn't he do anything...?

Well, the cannon that could be brought to bear can't hit Jack's ship because **the rocky outcrop is in the way**.

[image]

However, regardless of that, he doesn't have time to do that before he runs afoul of the rocks in the Devil's Triangle *literally seconds later*.